# Google Maps API v3 unable to center a map with a polyline marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am unable to center google maps containing a polyline marker after using setting `display: none` to the map container.

Initially, the map is displayed correctly, however after the toggle `hide() / show()` the map is centered so that the polyline marker is on the bottom-left corner. I've also tried the suggested solutions to use `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` but it didn't solve it.

The snippet. Note that `initMap` is triggered on some input change:

```
function initMap() {
    mapContainer = $("#mapContainer");
    mapObject = document.getElementById('map');

    if (substance === "NO2") {
        mapContainer.show();

        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        map = new google.maps.Map(mapObject, {
            center: center,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        });

        const point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(lat),
            parseFloat(lng)
        );

        var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            raiseOnDrag: true,
            labelContent: "123",
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 65),
            labelClass: "icon",
            labelInBackground: false,
            icon: {
                path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                fillColor: colorBackground,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: colorBorder,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                scale: 2
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(mapContainer).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are initializing the map each time `(substance === "NO2")` is true.